# Javascript add input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm pretty new to coding and can't find my error. Why isn't this working? It doesn't change anything on the website and the syntax is incorrect on sublime. It's supposed to add a new input at the end of the form. It's something with the syntax. #add is accesable. Don't know what to change the syntax error is on line

var html = '  Antwoord        
 ';}

```
    </head>
<body>
<!--navigatie -->

  <div class="container">
      <nav>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 studentdocent">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Docent</button>
         <a href="student.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Student</button> </a>
         </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
         <h1 class="head"> Meerkeuzevragen</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



<form action="jsonswitch.php" method="post">
<div class="container">


<!-- Oefening input -->
<div class="all">
<div id="toevoeg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label>Naam van de oefening</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="tbox" class="form-control" name="oefening" placeholder="Naam van de oefening">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- vraag input -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label>Zet hier je vraag neer</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="tbox" class="form-control" name="vraag" placeholder="Voer hier je vraag in..">
      </div>
    </div>



<!-- antwoord input -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label>Antwoord A</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="tbox" class="form-control" name="antwoorda" placeholder="Zet hier antwoord a neer...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label>Antwoord B</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="tbox" class="form-control" name="antwoordb" placeholder="Zet hier antwoord b neer...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label>Antwoord C</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3">
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="tbox" class="form-control" name="antwoordc" placeholder="Zet hier antwoord c neer...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label>Antwoord D</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4">
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="tbox" class="form-control" name="antwoordd" placeholder="Zet hier antwoord d neer...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>








<!-- Verstuur button  -->
  <div class="col-md-4">
<button class="upload btn btn-info fa fa-upload" type="submit"></button>

<button class="upload btn btn-success fa fa-plus" id="add"></button>

<button class="upload btn btn-danger fa fa-minus" id="remove"></button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(e){
//variabelen
var html = '<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-12"> <label>Antwoord</label> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4"> </div> <input type="text" id="childmake" class="form-control" name="antwoordd" placeholder="Zet hier antwoord d neer..."> </div> </div> </div>
</div> '/;

//input toevoegen
$("#add").click(function(e){
  $("#all").append(html);
});
```

Comment: Maybe remove the slash at the end of the `html` assignment

Comment: Trying running $("#add") in your browser console to see, if the element on which you are trigerring is present.

Comment: Did you look at the error in your browser's developer console? I see one syntax error by just glancing at the code

Comment: epascarello, i did this is giving the error but i don't know how to fix it: var html = '<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-12"> <label>Antwoord</label> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4"> </div> <input type="text" id="childmake" class="form-control" name="antwoordd" placeholder="Zet hier antwoord d neer..."> </div> </div> </div>

Comment: that's not an error

Comment: It would be handy if you included your (part of) html as well. Specifically the #add, #all tags

Comment: Your code has a line break in it before the div, strings can not have a line break in it. You also have a / before the semicolon, that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  var html = '<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-12"> <label>Antwoord</label> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4"> </div> <input type="text" id="childmake" class="form-control" name="antwoordd" placeholder="Zet hier antwoord d neer..."></div></div></div></div>';

  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    $("#all").append(html);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add"></input>
<p>
  Html will be added after this ...
</p>
<div id="all"></div>
```

I have also created a jsfiddle for your query here: https://jsfiddle.net/erLcrk9z/1/

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

why you added '/' at the end of html variable? Please remove this.

And also closing braces for ready() is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You add this `'/;` , the slash at the end, also you have an extra `</div>`

This code works:

```js
var html ='<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-12"> <label>Antwoord</label> <div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4"> </div> <input type="text" id="childmake" class="form-control" name="antwoordd" placeholder="Zet hier antwoord d neer..."> </div></div></div>';

$("#add").click(function(e){
  $("#all").append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add
</button>
<div id="all">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `html` isn't correctly set, and your code doesn't end correctly:

1. The line break before the last `div` was a problem (strings can't have a line break in it)
2. The `/` has nothing to do in your variable just before the `;`
3. Closing braces for `ready()` are missing.

⋅
⋅
⋅

Here is a working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  //variabelen
  var html = '<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-12"> <label>Antwoord</label> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4"> </div> <input type="text" id="childmake" class="form-control" name="antwoordd" placeholder="Zet hier antwoord d neer..."> </div> </div> </div> </div>';

  //input toevoegen
  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    $("#all").append(html);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="all"></div>
```